# Trying to Identify Static or Thermal Transfer Tape

Tags: solid-state-devices, antistatic, ssd

I came accross this solidstate drive which is in a custom plasic and metal enclosure.
There is a sheet of material cut out between the metal top and the drive. I'm trying to figure out what it is, it's pinker than in the it looks in the picture below, and you can see it's a bit "crumbly", and has a mesh backing where the adhesive is.

Trying to establish if it's a type of antistatic tape, or thermal? or even just vibration dampening. but ive never seen anything quite like this material.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Most likely thermal. Static only needs a small contact patch.